# How to cast string into dict?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

There is one site that returns response in string like:

```
{"ConsignorName": "first part "second part""}
```

which should be JSON. Result should be

```
{'ConsignorName': 'first part "second part"'}
```

And I can't just `json.loads(data)` because it fails with

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter:...`
```

So I somehow need to cast this string in dict. Maybe you know some way to do this?

Comment: There isn't one, that JSON is broken. You need to fix it upstream.

Comment: Agreed, that this problem should be resolved at the source. But if due to some reasons you have to treat the old data and it cannot be recreated, then you have to give more information. With the example. that you gave I have the impression, that there will be no generic solution. Perhaps if you characterize the nature of the data well enough, there might be a way to fix it just for your special case.

Is the problem only with "ConsignoreName"? Can we assume, that the character } will never be part of the value string? will the string always be in one line?

Answer (score 1):

```
d = {"ConsignorName": "first part \"second part\""}
```

In my humble opintion, you need to escape the `"` inside the string.
Otherwise, JSON will expect correctly after `"first part "` a `,`.

You write and load into/from `json` from within `python` this way:

```
# write
with open("test.json", "w") as out: 
    json.dump(d, fp=out) 

# read
with open("test.json") as fin: 
    myd = json.load(fin)
```

`myd` is then:

```
myd
## {'ConsignorName': 'first part "second part"'}
```

Answer (score -2):

{"ConsignorName": "first part "second part""}

is it really the return from the sites?
It is not a valid json at all.

There should be a escape character in front of "second...

Comment: That was already explained in the comments. This is not a solution.